# Doctrine: how to curb circular references

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have devices being parts of brands and repairs being part of devices. Now I'm trying to get a simple AJAX call which will allow me to search for a device by either brand name or device name. Unfortunately, I get circular references. Even when I've written a handler for circular references to limit it to one, I still get too much information in my objects.

Consider the following return from serialize on my DQL query:

> [{"0":{"id":1,"name":"iPhone
>   1","logo":"iPhone1","brand":{"id":2,"name":"Apple","logo":"apple","devices":["iPhone
>   1",{"id":2,"name":"iPhone","logo":"iphone","brand":"Apple","deletedAt":null,"repairs":[]}],"deletedAt":null},"deletedAt":null,"repairs":[]},"name":"Apple"},{"0":{"id":2,"name":"iPhone","logo":"iphone","brand":{"id":2,"name":"Apple","logo":"apple","devices":[{"id":1,"name":"iPhone
>   1","logo":"iPhone1","brand":"Apple","deletedAt":null,"repairs":[]},"iPhone"],"deletedAt":null},"deletedAt":null,"repairs":[]},"name":"Apple"}]

Here I don't even need repairs at all. However, since it is referenced in the PartEntity, I still get a bunch of unnecessary repair info. How can I limit the data I get out of an object?

my Controller code:

```
public function ajaxShowDevicesAction(Request $request) {
    //if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $data = $request->query->get('data');
        $result = "";
        if ($data) {
            $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Device')->findAllByBrandOrName($data);
        }
        if ($result) {
            $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
            $normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
            $normalizers[0]->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
                return $object->getName();
            });
            $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
            $jsoncontent = $serializer->serialize($result, 'json');
            $response = new Response($jsoncontent);
            return $response;
        }
        // else { # unsure how to give a "no results" response
        //     $response = new Response(json_encode(array()));
        //     $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        //     return $response;
        // }
    // } else {
    //     throw new HttpException(403, "Ajax access only");
    // }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
setCircularReferenceLimit()
```

method for normalizers.

[Handling Circular References](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references)

Comment: It was set to 1. So I should set it to 0? Is it even possible to determine what data is passed to an object? For optimization purposes, it isn't always necessary to even know the name of the brand of a device, so I'd cut it out.